# Detect same scenes in video file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, computer-vision, video-processing

Is there any way to detect repeating video sequence in large video file? I wanted to crop video when it recognizes same sequence?

e.g. big file contains 
`(seq1-----------seq1---------seq1---------)` 
and I need from this 3 files with 
`(seq1-----------)`. Here seq1 is more-less same video sequence with duration of 10 seconds.

Comment: Let's say seq1 starts with frame A. Can frame A appear outside seq1?

Comment: Theoretically it can be black frame so yes. but seq1 will be unique.

Comment: How about the middle frame? Technically ffmpeg can't identify matching sequences. Your best bet is to identify a unique frame in the seq, then locate those, then compare the surrounding frames with adjacent frames in the reference video.